# Tailwind style doesn't seems to be apply inside Material-ui Drawer component in NextJs

Tags: next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css

I am trying to add styling inside a **@mui/material/drawer** component using tailwind.

```
import { Close } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { Box, Drawer, IconButton, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useContext} from "react";
import { SearchContext } from "store/context";

export default function SearchDrawer() {
  const { search, setSearchMode } = useContext(SearchContext);

  return (
    <Drawer open={search.searchMode} anchor="bottom">

      <Box sx={{ height: "100vh" }} className="bg-red-500">
      <IconButton onClick={() => { setSearchMode(!search.searchMode); }}><Close/></IconButton>
        <div>
          <TextField variant="outlined" sx={{display: 'block'}}/>
          <TextField variant="outlined" sx={{display: 'block'}}/>
        </div>
      </Box>

    </Drawer>
  );
}
```

Expected behavior is

`<Box sx={{ height: "100vh" }} className="bg-red-500">`

This line of code will make whole screen red, But Nothing happen.
[Output after render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8COd.png)
Tailwind styles are not applying on some of Material-ui components like "Drawer", "Dialog", "ToolTip" This all components are hover over other components.

[Tailwindcss classes are not working in Tooltip & Dialog components #33424 - GitHub](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33424)

This page says to modify material-ui theme,

```
        defaultProps: {
          container: rootElement,
        },
     },
```

But **rootElement** is available in Reactjs, How to do it on Nextjs.

Comment: How were you able to fix this? I tried both the solutions, but neither of them worked for me

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me using MUI v5 and Next 12 with Tailwind 3:

```
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';
import { createTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@mui/material/styles';

const rootElement = () => document.getElementById('__next');

// Create a theme instance.
const theme = responsiveFontSizes(
    createTheme({
        components: {
            MuiPopover: {
                defaultProps: {
                    container: rootElement,
                },
            },
            MuiPopper: {
                defaultProps: {
                    container: rootElement,
                },
            },
            MuiDialog: {
                defaultProps: {
                    container: rootElement,
                },
            },
            MuiModal: {
                defaultProps: {
                    container: rootElement,
                },
            },
        },
        palette: {
            primary: {
                main: '#546DE5',
            },
        },
    }),
);

export default theme;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me from the official docs :

1. Remove Tailwind CSS's preflight style so it can use the MUI's preflight instead (CssBaseline).

In your file **tailwind.config.js** add the following :

```
  //Remove Tailwind CSS's preflight style so it can use the MUI's preflight instead
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
```

2. Add the important option, using the id of your app wrapper. For example, #__next for Next.js and "#root" for CRA:

In your file **tailwind.config.js** add the following (for nextjs add **#__next**):

```
  //Add the important option, using the id of your app wrapper. For example, #__next for Next.js and "#root" for CRA
  important: '#__next',
```

Your file **tailwind.config.js** should like like :

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],

  //Add the important option, using the id of your app wrapper. For example, #__next for Next.js and "#root" for CRA
  important: '#__next',
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],

  //Remove Tailwind CSS's preflight style so it can use the MUI's preflight instead
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
}
```

3. Fix the CSS injection order. Most CSS-in-JS solutions inject their styles at the bottom of the HTML , which gives MUI precedence over Tailwind CSS. To reduce the need for the important property, you need to change the CSS injection order. Here's a demo of how it can be done in MUI:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

export default function GlobalCssPriority() {
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      {/* Your component tree. Now you can override MUI's styles. */}
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}
```

You can check the official documentation : https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css

Answer (score 0):

For NextJS, you have to wrap "getElementById" in a callback:

```js
MuiDrawer: {
  defaultProps: {
    // container: document.getElementById("__next"), // ❌ Wrong
    container: () => document.getElementById("__next"), // ✅ Correct
  },
},
```

Just remember that you have to do this to ALL hover components you use (Drawer, Dialog, etc.):

```js
const rootElement = () => document.getElementById("__next");

export const theme = createTheme({
  // ...
  MuiPopover: {
    defaultProps: {
      container: rootElement,
    },
  },

  MuiPopper: {
    defaultProps: {
      container: rootElement,
    },
  },

  MuiDrawer: {
    defaultProps: {
      container: rootElement,
    },
  },

  MuiModal: {
    defaultProps: {
      container: rootElement,
    },
  },

  // ... and all the other hover components
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, I have been trying to get tailwind working with material-ui autocomplete component from past few days with no success. I tried your suggestion, but still can't get it working. If you don't mind, could you please share a sample github repo where you have configured this? Thanks!