# Other solution of Tailwind don't work on MUI portal components (ex: Dialog)

Tags: material-ui, dialog, tailwind-css

At first, I would like to tell you what I have known about this question.

1. The reason is that portal component(ex: Dialog, Menu) don't inside in the root element(#__next or #root).
2. To solved it, I can just override container of defaultProps, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73810671/tailwind-style-doesnt-seems-to-be-apply-inside-material-ui-drawer-component-in)

It seems that setting a container for each portal component is not a perfect solution, as there is a possibility of leaving some components out.

Is any other solution?